# Did I connect my Listview to simpleadapter?

Tags: java, android, xml, simpleadapter

[image]
 Can someone fix it?
Can someone tells me that why the compiler doesn't allow me to do that? I watch this from online tutorial.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Please post all text as text.

Comment: You should import the `java.lang.Object` instead of `java.util.Objects`

Comment: use Map<String, **Object** > map=new......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `Object` not `Objects`, but it's recommended to make it the specific data type you want to input in your map(`Integer` in your case) and this way you can make use of compile time checking of data types instead of doing that in run time. For example, you can't make it an Integer and input anything in it except Integers.

Comment: Mmmm. Actually it's complicated. You can say that it is. All objects in java inherits from Object so they are all objects indeed.

Comment: Gotcha Thanks very much.